# Get Current User from root mode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-carbon, bsd

I am writing a login item and I am trying to find if its possible to get the current user.

Lets say, I have logged in with user "Test" and when I execute the exe with root privileges and if I use

```
char *user  = getenv("USER");
```

user is "root".

My expected answer is "Test".

How can I get it?

I don't know if I can put objective c code in login item? Is it possible to NSUserName in login item.

```
NSString *user = NSUserName();
```

Comment: See ***getlogin*** in man page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [the `SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser).

[QA1133](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1133/) gives some relevant details and caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Login items can be Cocoa applications, so you can use `NSUserName()` (which is in Foundation by the way).

Maybe also look at [getuid() / geteuid()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getuid.2.html)

Comment: I tried NSUserName(), its value is root & I also tried getuid()/geteuid() both gives value 0. So, its not working.

Comment: @MachinTosh: If getuid() is 0, the real user is root and there is nothing to be done.  Can you arrange to pass the user id some other way?