# How to get the logged on user from a process running as root?

Tags: c++, macos

I have a program running as root and call another program to run(A).

I want A to run when the user logs on. I've used command: `su - 'username' -c A`,

or in the A main function, I've called: `setuid(current_uid_logged)`.

But I don't know the way to get the user-name of the logged on user, or the uid in the root process.

Ways that I've tried: `getenv("USERNAME")` or `getlogin()` always return `root` account.

I've confused with `getlogin()`, my program is running when kernel start and wait for user login (I have a thread to wait a Finder process (Mac OSX) running to detect user logged on), wait 10 seconds and call `getlogin()` but sometime, it returned `root` but can return user login. I think Finder process is running when user logged on.

But when I call my app to run with `sudo` command, `getlogin()` always returns current user logged on.

How do I do this?

Comment: To me this seems to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583338/get-current-user-from-root-mode where a good answer is provided.

Answer (score 1):

`getlogin(3)` returns the name of the user who owns the process's controlling terminal. This has *nothing* to do with the username of whoever might log in to the GUI of the operating system. Instead, `getlogin(3)` and `getuid(2)` will only ever return the name / uid of the user account that *started* the program -- they have more to do with the process history than with any user sitting in front of the computer.

There are similar stories with the environment variables `USER` and `LOGNAME` -- if either one was set in a process, it was by a process higher in the process's call tree. It too cannot be influenced by whichever user eventually sits in front of the computer.

I'm sure there *is* some mechanism to discover the currently-logged-on user on an OS X machine, but it won't be a traditional Unix API that provides it to you.

Answer (score 0):

how about `uid_t getuid()`?

more details at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getuid.2.html